# How to implement getStaticProps in a layout

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Next.JS layouts can be used to persist page state, but apparently not API calls. The [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#data-fetching) say to use SWR or `useEffect` to fetch data on page layouts, but this is a bad experience for data that is static, such as data that goes into a footer. For example, fetching a street address for a footer should not be done on the client, but on the server.

With all that being said - is it possible to call `getStaticProps` on a layout? Or is there another way to fetch data server-side for a layout?

Comment: That's not possible. Fetch data at the page level then pass it down to your components.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use Next.js data fetching methods inside of Next.js "page files" (files inside `./pages/` or `./src/pages/`.

Layout components can't use these methods; however, they CAN expect props to be passed to them in a certain way.

So, while you can't add data fetching logic to the reusability of a Layout component, you can require props such that devs will need to use a data fetching method to provide the props as the layout component expects.